# I want to edit a product in the admin panel but I keep getting this error "Attempt to assign property "title" on null". Laravel 9 Database error

Tags: php, laravel, properties, null

My Controller.php  I have checked the similar things online but I have not been able to solve it.

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Models\Category;
use App\Models\Product;

class AdminController extends Controller
{
    public function view_category()
    {
        $data=category::all();

        return view('admin.category',compact('data'));
    }
    public function add_category(Request $request)
    {
        $data=new category;
        $data->category_name=$request->category;
        $data->save();
        return redirect()->back()->with('message','Category added successfully');
    }

    public function delete_category($id)
    {
        $data=category::find($id);
        $data->delete();
        return redirect()->back()->with('message', 'Category deleted successfully');
    }

    public function view_product()
    {
        $category=category::all();
        return view('admin.product',compact('category'));
    }
```

Add new product in the controller. Everything works well here

```
    public function add_product(Request $request)
    {
       $product=new product;
       $product->title=$request->title;
       $product->description=$request->description;
       $image=$request->image;
       $imagename=time().'.'.$image->getClientOriginalExtension();
       $request->image->move('product',$imagename);
       $product->image=$imagename;
       $product->price=$request->price;
       $product->quantity=$request->quantity;
       $product->category=$request->category;
       $product->descount_price=$request->des_price;
       $product->location=$request->location;
       $product->save();

       return redirect()->back()->with('message','product added successfully');
    }

    public function show_product()
    {
        $product=product::all();
        return view('admin.show_product',compact('product'));
    }
```

Code for delete in the controller which is also working very well

```
    public function delete_product($id)
    {
        $product=product::find($id);
        $product->delete();
        return redirect()->back()->with('message','product deleted successfully');
    }

    public function update($id)
    {
        $category=category::all();
        $product=product::find($id); //declare variable
        return view('admin.update',compact('product','category')); //compact (product) means getting the id from the variable declared

    }

    public function update_confirm(Request $request,$id) 
    {
        $product=product::find($id);
        $product->title=$request->title; //This is where the error occurs
        $product->description=$request->description;
        $image->$request->image;
        $imagename=time().'.'.$image->getClientOriginalExtention();
        $request->image->move('/product',$imagename);
        return redirect()->back();
        $product->image=$imagename;
        $product->save();
        $product->category=$request->category;
        $product->quantity=$request->quantity;
        $product->price=$request->price;
        $product->descount_price=$request->descount_price;
        $product->location=$request->location;
       

    }
}
```

Edit Code in the view blade. Apart from edit everything works well in the system.

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <base href="/public">
  @include('admin.header')

  <style type="text/css">

        .center
        {
            text-align: center;
            padding-top: 40px;
        }

        .font_size
        {
            font-size: 40px;
            padding-bottom: 40px;
        }
        .text_color
        {
            color: black;
            padding-bottom: 20px;
        }
        label
        {
          display: inline-block;
          width: 200px;
        }
        .design
        {
          padding-bottom: 15px
        }
        .div_submit
        {
          text-align: center;
        }
        
        

    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="container-scroller">
      <!-- partial:partials/_sidebar.html -->
      @include('admin.sidebar')
      <!-- partial -->
      @include('admin.navbar')
        <!-- partial -->
        <div class="main-panel">
          <div class="content-wrapper">

          @if(session()->has('message'))

          <div class="alert alert-success">
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-hidden="true">x</button>
              {{session()->get('message')}}

          </div>

            @endif

            <div class="center">
              <h1 class="font_size">Add Product</h1>
              <form action="{{url('/update_confirm','$product->id')}}" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                @csrf 
              <div class="design">
              <label>Product Title</label>
              <input class="text_color" type="text" name="title" placeholder="Product title" required=""
              value="{{$product->title}}">
              </div>

              <div class="design">
              <label>Product Description</label>
              <input class="text_color" type="text" name="description" placeholder="Product description" required=""
              value="{{$product->description}}">
              </div>

              <div class="design">
              <label>Current Product image</label>
              <img style="margin: auto;" height="20" width="50" src="/product/{{$product->image}}">
              </div>

              <div class="design">
              <label>Change Product image</label>
              <input type="file" name="image">
              </div>

              <div class="design">
              <label>Product price</label>
              <input class="text_color" type="number" name="price" placeholder="Product price" required=""
              value="{{$product->price}}">
              </div>

              <div class="design">
              <label>Product Quantity</label>
              <input class="text_color" type="number" min="0" name="quantity" placeholder="Product quantity" required=""
              value="{{$product->quantity}}">
              </div>

              <div class="design">
              <label >Product Category</label>
              <select class="text_color" name="category" required="">
              <option value="{{$product->caregory}}" selected="">Select Category</option>

              @foreach($category as $category)
                <option value="{{$category->category_name}}">{{$category->category_name}}</option>
                @endforeach
             
              </select>
              </div>

              <div class="design">
              <label>Product Discount Price</label>
              <input class="text_color" type="text" name="des_price" placeholder="descount price" 
              value="{{$product->descount_price}}">
              </div>

              <div class="design">
              <label>Product Location</label>
              <input class="text_color" type="text" name="location" placeholder="Shop location" required="" 
              value="{{$product->location}}">
              </div>
            </div>

             <div class="div_submit">
              <input type="submit" value="Update product" class="btn btn-primary">
              </div>

              </form>

          </div>
            </div>
              </div>
    <!-- container-scroller -->
    <!-- plugins:js -->
    @include('admin.script')
  </body>
</html>
```

Codes in database

```
Schema::create('products', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->id();
            $table->string('title')->nullable();
            $table->string('description')->nullable();
            $table->string('image')->nullable();
            $table->string('category')->nullable();
            $table->string('quantity')->nullable();
            $table->string('price')->nullable();
            $table->string('descount_price')->nullable();
            $table->string('location')->nullable();
            $table->timestamps();
```

Comment: add your edit button code in the question.. in your update_confirm method, this is not getting a product with the id parameter. and why you have code after the return? nothing will be executed after return.

Comment: That is what I have added in the blade view. It stops at title. That return is for the image, after changing the image it should remain on the same page

Comment: probably `$id` doesn't exist , change this line to `product::findOrFail($id);`

Comment: product::findOrFail($id); adding this gives me ''not found'' error. It shows this in the adress bar in the browser; update_confirm/%24product->id

Comment: %24product->id is not a valid product id, right? in your edit button, product id is not parsed correctly.. that is why i asked you to add the edit button/form action code

Comment: I've added the complete edit code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in your form;

```
<form action="{{url('/update_confirm','$product->id')}}" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
```

You have quotes around the product->id which means that it is treated as a literal string and not a php variable.  Remove the quotes

In the update function, you need to remove the return line part way through the function, spell extension correctly, and also save the product at the end of the function;

```php
    public function update_confirm(Request $request,$id) 
    {
        $product = product::findOrFail($id);
        $product->title = $request->title;
        $product->description = $request->description;
        if($request->file('image') {
            $imagename=time().'.'.$image->getClientOriginalExtension();
            $request->image->move('product',$imagename);
            $product->image=$imagename;
        }
        $product->category = $request->category;
        $product->quantity = $request->quantity;
        $product->price = $request->price;
        $product->descount_price = $request->descount_price;
        $product->location = $request->location;

        $product->save();
       
        return redirect()->back();
```

by the way, it is `discount` not `descount`

And VALIDATE user input

Comment: I have done exactly that but the same error still appear

Comment: ok, so NOW what do you see in the URL when the error occurs